# failed to compile when creating a build for react production

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm deploying my Django/React website, when i do a sudo npm run build it failed to compile with multiple errors   :

```
Failed to compile.

[eslint] 
src/components/features/card/index.jsx
  Line 2:10:  'Link' is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  Line 4:18:  'image' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
  Line 4:18:  'image' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
  Line 4:25:  'alt' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  Line 4:30:  'bottomText' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  Line 4:42:  'text' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
  Line 4:48:  'link' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
  Line 4:48:  'link' is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  Line 22:5:  Missing an explicit type attribute for button  react/button-has-type

src/components/form/index.jsx
  Line 15:17:  'loginError' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
  Line 15:38:  'loginLoading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

src/components/login/index.jsx
  Line 8:22:  'page' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

src/redux/actions/authActions/index.js
  Line 2:10:  'useNavigate' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 3:1:   Dependency cycle via ./actions:3         import/no-cycle

src/redux/actions/index.js
  Line 1:1:  Dependency cycle via ../..:12  import/no-cycle
  Line 2:1:  Dependency cycle via ../..:2   import/no-cycle

src/redux/actions/userActions/index.js
  Line 2:1:  Dependency cycle via ./actions:3  import/no-cycle

src/redux/index.js
  Line 3:1:  Dependency cycle via ./authActions:1                  import/no-cycle
  Line 4:1:  Dependency cycle via ../reducers:4=>./authReducers:1  import/no-cycle
```

how can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

To ignore eslint errors:

First add a file named .env.development.local inside the root ditectory of your project
Then add this line to it

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
```

Now you can run build without error.